# Performing post-hoc tests on a GLM with Gamma distribution

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, multiple-comparisons, gamma-distribution, post-hoc

I am analyzing data that is gamma distributed. Hence, an ANVOA was a good choice but a GLM with gamma distribution worked well. To report the data I want to compare all groups to the control treatment and use the Holm method for adjusting the p-value. For this I used the glht function in r (multicomp package) and this also worked well.

**My concern is the following:**

Is it correct to use the glht or similar package (such as emmeans) if the data are not normally distributed or should I use a different way of performing the post-hoc tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem using those packages.  They have methods that recognize the model was fitted with `glm()` instead of `lm()` and adjust appropriately.