# Assumptions and validity of post-hoc pairwise comparisons of GLMs

Tags: generalized-linear-model, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

How does packages for pairwise comparisons such as multcomp's `glht(mcp)` and emmeans `pairs()` maintain validity in cases of heterogeneity of variance and non-normality of response or residuals - e.g. if fitting a model of the type `glmmTMB(y ~ factor(a) + b, family = tweedie(link = "log"))`?

In a related question, ([Performing post-hoc tests on a GLM with Gamma distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/552430/performing-post-hoc-tests-on-a-glm-with-gamma-distribution)), it was claimed these packages adjust for GLMs. However, a more thorough explaination as to how this adjustment is done and whether any limitations other than the models' applies would be useful.

According to the glht [documentation](https://faculty.washington.edu/linoue/multcomp.pdf), results for other models than `lm` rely on the normal approximation. Is a correct interpretation of [Hothorn (2008)](https://core.ac.uk/reader/12163061) that the assumption - other than the glm model used - is that model parameter estimates are normally distributed with basis in the central limit theorem?